# cloudfoundry application versioning and rollback

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm using cloudfoundry local deployment. I can push apps to the cf instance. I've the following questions:

1. Each time an app is pushed, is it versioned?
2. How to check the running version?
3. How to rollback to the previous version, if required?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Application versioning is not currently (Jan 2015) a feature of Cloud Foundry standard, although I thought I saw it on the roadmap but am unable to find it in the tracker at the moment. Versioning in a repository such as Git will have to be done before pushing a new version of your app.

ActiveState's enhanced, commercial version of Cloud Foundry called "Stackato" has this feature among other enhancements.